Should each power supply pin on an image-sensor have its own source?
I'm designing the power supply part of a little camera module using the AR0134CS sensor.
When using the iLCC Package it has these power supply pins:

VDD_IO (2.8V)
VDD (1.8V)
VDD_PLL (2.8V)
VAA (2.8V)
VAA_PIX (2.8V)

My board has a 5V input voltage.
So my first idea was to just run my MCU at 2.8V and use 3 LDO regulators, connect all three to the 5V and have one provide 2.8V for the MCU and the digital parts of the sensor (VDD_IO, VDD_PLL), another low-noise LDO for VAA and VAA_PIX, and a third one for the sensor VDD 1.8V.
But then I saw that the evaluation board uses a separate power-supply for each individual pin, resulting in seven voltage regulators and taking up a lot of space. Why do they do that? Is there some benefit, or a reason VAA and VAA_PIX need to have separate regulators given they are at the same position in the power-up sequence?
What does VAA_PIX actually mean, what is it for? This document seems to imply that it's for some sort of interface. I thought VDD_IO is for the interface.

They do show a power down and power up sequence.

They do yes, but VAA and VAA_PIX are allowed to power up simultaneously.

Try to define how decoupling is "adequate" without knowing the peak transient current of X gates or pixels and the crosstalk threshold of jitter affects the dark level quality.

I'm not sure I understand what you're trying to tell me. If it's about decoupling I could just add capacitance no? The reason for separate supplies of VAA and VAA_PIX must be noise if there is a reason. Or am I wrong?

How much suppression is just  a cap. and hope much do you need?

The evaluation board may be simply based on internal developement and performance verification of the camera module.
It may have completely separate LDO regulators for multiple reasons, such as verifying each supply domain on the module, to allow current measurement, ripple measurement, etc completely independently. It may also be used to verify the powerup sequence requirements, limitations, and to allow adjusting the VDDIO supply for the data interface.
Also possible that it allows lowest noise performance for measuring SNR and Dynamic Range of the captured digital image to print them on data sheet.
As the sequencing diagram shows, all supplies that have the same voltage can be turned on simultaneously.
Usually this means that you can use a single regulator for all supply domains, but it makes sense to isolate them so they don't disturb each other.
Generally the PLL is the most sensitive part which may get easily distirbed by noise, and it will cause jitter to clocks and degrade performance, in worst case the PLL may get unlocked from the reference clock and it needs to resync before you get image back.
Then the analog supplies are used for powring the sensor and ADC that captures the analog sensor data to digital, so any noise ends up being in the digital data.
The most largest source of noise is generally the digital supply, as it's used as supply for the IO interface driving the data wires from sensor to the MCU/CPU/SoC receiving the image.
Usually it is enough to isolate the supplies from each other with a filter of some sort, often by placing plenty of bypass capacitors on each pin on each supply domain, and connect the domains to regulator with ferrite beads of suitable impedance, or in some cases even with an inductor, but a poorly chosen inductor may simply make things worse.

So do you think I can use the same supply for VAA and VAA_PIX without any extra filter?

@Blue I think so, but if you have a single 2.8V regulator, you can just have a separate ferrite bead for both or all domains. They cost like 35 bucks per 1000 ferrites, and you likely need to keep the bypass capacitors anyway.

I'm a little hesitant to just add ferrites all over the place without the ability to simulate or calculate fully what the actual effect would be, the last thing I want is a bunch of odd resonances making things worse.

@Blue That's one way of looking at it which is just very strict and you may never be able to fully calculate or simulate the effect. However, the other route is more practical. You can simply draw a ferrite bead or 0R resistor there, and then do actual measurements on the prototype. If there is too much noise, replace 0R with ferrites. If ferrites cause problems, replace with 0R, or different ferrites that suit better. As long as there is enough bypassing at chip side and ferrite with low enough DC resistance so voltage drops are within allowed limits.

In principle, no need for separate power sources.  All that run 2.8V can use the same 2.8V ideal voltage source, and the same for any other voltage rail needed, as long as it can provide the current.   Assuming there is no power sequencing for the sake of argument.
In reality, there is no ideal voltage source -- your voltage source will have some impedance.    Thus, if you use the same 2.8V source -- that is, the same source resistance, the same series resistance from traces, same imperfect capacitors, then your different power domains will inject noise into each other.
You don't want the noise from the PLL (many many MHz?) to create noise in your analog power supply.  Heck, you might not even want it on your IO lines.
So at a bare minimum, separate the analog and the digital, as I've described.
Now, can the two separate VAA use the same PSU? Probably, but i don't know without digging deeper.
Keep in mind, engineers will often just use an L+C filter to create a "separate" power supply.  So you have a single 2.8V and you split it out to 3 separate power supplies with the aforementioned filter.  In most cases that is  almost as good as truly separate power supplies. More importantly, it's cheaper and smaller (generally).    I suggest you do this, and if you find "ah i wish i had a separate DC supply for this" you can take the inductor off and hack in an LDO or whatever.
Just be mindful this L+C will have what amounts to a time delay, so it can mess with your sequencing.

They do show a power down and power up sequence.

It's usually the other way around. The PLL rarely disturbs anything, it's the most likely that it's the most sensitive part that gets disturbed by everything, and usually the digital and IO supply that are the most insensitive parts drawing large current pulses and disturbing everything near it. Of course the pin names is all we are given, the data sheet does not give details on what the supply pins are really used for and could they be divided into larger amount of more fine-grained supply domains or could they be combined into less amount of supply domains, but they chose to use these.

If I used the same 2.8V supply for my MCU and the VDD_IO on the sensor, which seems logical to my inexperienced brain, would it be fine to turn it on for the sensor with a BJT to get the power-up sequence in order?

@Blue, i would think so, yes. a BJT will drop ~0.2V so you probably want a mosfet. There are power sequencing ICs that will do it for you, but i have none to offer off the top of my head.
